# validation for Password is at least 6 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to perform JavaScript validation on a password.

It must meet the following criteria:

- at least 6 characters long
- at least 1 capital letter
- at least 1 lowercase letter
- at least 1 number
- at least 1 punctuation mark

Comment: Paste your code, then we indicate the error

Comment: Please add the "javascript" tag if you want to get more answers.

Comment: It is VERY important to point out that use of JavaScript to validate a password implies that the code will run in a browser, rather than on a server.  This is a bad security pattern - client side security - which can be easily bypassed.  It's fine to do this as a usability feature or as an attempt to minimize load on the server (by having errors occur on the client) but your app will not be securely written if your server does not independently validate the password, regardless of the client's result.

Comment: What I find is good pratice is to:
1. Validate in the browser
2. Validate on the server with the exact same regex. If it fails, you know it is a person of malicious interest, and that you should log it. Beside that throw a internal server error, so the person will think he caused something to happen. It will waste lot of his/hers time.

Comment: @Martinb Is bypassing a feature that is meant to protect a user from himself (giving himself an insecure password) really "malicious"?

Comment: If you program your javascript correctly, short answer yes. I a regex validation of usernames on my site, which makes it impossible to send a request for making a new user unless it is validated correctly. If I get a request which does not validate on the server, it is highly likely that the person has a malicious purpose. And I just send back a header, saying the server made some unintentional error(like it was a coding error). This is of course not the only security you should have, but it helps keeping lot of script kiddies at bay, by let them search for a hole, there simply isn't at there.

Comment: On this topic: if you have any decision-making power in this situation, [this is actually not a great way to handle password security](http://xkcd.com/936/). Please don't require numbers, symbols and capitals in passwords. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it using an array of regular expressions:

```
/** 
  * Returns true if pw is a valid password.
  */

function isValid(pw) {

    if (! pw) {
        return false;
    }

    var rgx = [
        /.{6,}/,
        /[A-Z]/,
        /[a-z]/,
        /[0-9]/, 
        /[@#$&*^%!+=\/\\[\]|?.,<>)(;:'"~`]/
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < rgx.length; i++) {
        if (rgx[i].test(pw) === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;        
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EuuUq/3/)

You could make it more flexible by passing the regex array as a parameter.

[More reading about regex.test() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

---

Here's the more readable, academic edition:

```
function isValid(s) { 
    // check for null or too short
    if (!s || s.length < 6) {
        return false;
    }
    // check for a number
    if (/[0-9]/.test(s) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    // check for a capital letter
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(s) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    // check for a lowercase letter
    if (/[a-z]/.test(s) === false) {
        return false;
    }     
    // check for punctuation mark
    if (/[@#$&*^%!+=\/\\[\]|?.,<>)(;:'"~`]/.test(s) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    // all requirements have been satisfied
    return true; 
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EuuUq/1/).

Answer (score 0):

The validation can be done using a single regex:

```
var pw = "letMe1n!"; // Read this from an <input> field

// Validation:    
if (/^(?=.*[.,?!])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,}/.test(pw)) {
  // The password is valid!
}
```

The set of punctuation characters, `[.,?!]` can be extended if needed.